# Why can mutableCopy not be used on NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsnumber

Code:

```
NSNumber* i = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:1.0];
NSNumber* j = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

j= [i mutableCopy];
```

When running `j= [i mutableCopy]`, the program crashes.

I know `NSNumber` is an immutable type; when you use `copy`, `i` and `j` will have the same memory address (reference copy). But when you are using `mutableCopy`, it should perform a value copy. Why can `mutableCopy` not be used on `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSNumber` class is not conformed to `NSMutableCopying` protocol, so it not responds to `mutableCopy` selector. There is no class like `NSMutableNumber` in Cocoa. An `NSNumber` object is a simple container for a single C data item to use it with APIs that require Objective-C objects. If you need to perform any number mutation, you use scalar C types for that.